# Globally Unique IPv6 Address on a VM running ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, ipv6

For testing purposes, I'd like to be able to deploy VM's running Ubuntu that have globally unique IPv6 addresses. The VM software is Virtualbox.

I am able to make link local addresses (as said by ifconfig:  inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fef7:30a7/64 Scope:Link) , using a Host-only Adapter, but I'm unsure how to receive global unique ones.

Any advice?

Comment: Do you already have a global IPv6 range assigned?

Comment: I don't believe so no. I've tried to follow the advice on this website (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IPv6) but no dice

Comment: I suggest you ask your ISP for IPv6. If they cannot provide you with IPv6 then complain and get a free tunnel with IPv6 addresses from tunnelbroker.net in the mean time